# Change text inside dynamic div when on select change is made jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a title for my drop down that is dynamically given and I can currently change it when the page loads. But once I select an item from the drop down it changes back. I am looking for a simple jquery js solution that can help keep the name when an item is selected.

I need to change the text in: #shippingStateSpan  from Destination State -> Destination Province and leave that way even after something is selected.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="shippingStateDiv">
    <span id="shippingStateSpan">Destination State<br />
    </span>
    <select name="shippingState" id="shippingState" class="shippingDropDown"
         onchange="ApplyTaxRate(this.value,4040828,1,1,0);">
             <option value="-1" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
             <option value="129654">AB</option>
             <option value="129653">BC</option>
             <option value="129652">MB</option>
             <option value="129647">NB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my js I use to make the change on initially (But it changes back after I select something) I assume a jquery .on function may be possible but I an not sure how to do it. Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#shippingStateSpan").text("Destination Province");
</script>
```

Comment: What happens in the `ApplyTaxRate` function?

Comment: Why don't you read about `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/ and then post code if it still doesn't work?

Comment: destination province should be AB if you select AB, bc if you select BC and so on... ?

Comment: ApplyTaxRate: Adds that province tax to the products in the cart. I tried some .on jquery but I can't get it to work. My jquery is not the best.  The value does not matter as they will all be provinces.

Comment: I've not understend, but check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEpvS/) can be a starter point

Comment: Hi Alex, You seem to be on the right track, but I want the title to always be Destination Province not the values.

Comment: Ah check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TEpvS/5/)

Comment: That works on select now! How can I combine it so it works on page load as well?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $select = $('#shippingState'),
      $span = $('#shippingStateSpan');

  $select.on('change', function(){

    $span.html('Destination Province');

  });

});
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I try this.

Comment: Which jQuery library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
​$(function() {

    $('#shippingState').on('change', function() {

        $('#shippingStateSpan').text('Destination Province')
    });

});​
```

Check out the working example here http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zp7bA/